# google map: how to get address in android

Tags: android, google-maps

How to get the location or address from the google map when i am click on a particular address. IS it possible to use map overlay to collect the address from the map view.

Comment: belove link help you how to get location address from google map ..try it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084065/get-map-address-or-location-address-in-android

Answer (score 12):

Please Use below code for get address.

```
try {
    Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(youractivityclassname.this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = geo.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    if (addresses.isEmpty()) {
        yourtextfieldname.setText("Waiting for Location");
    }
    else {
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            yourtextfieldname.setText(addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getLocality() +", " + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Address:- " + addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + addresses.get(0).getLocality(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // getFromLocation() may sometimes fail
}
```

And see below link for more information and complete example.

[Using Google Maps in Android](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)